# Make Django Create Foreign Keys for MySQL Backend

Tags: python, mysql, django

How do you force Django to create real foreign key constraints when using a MySQL backend? If I'm reading this [old bug report](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5729) correctly, Django should be creating real foreign keys, but my default Django 1.2.3 setup using MySQL only generates indexes for models.ForeignKey().

Comment: Are you using innodb or myisam as your default table type?

Comment: @marr75, I'm using the default type, MyISAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your database engine to InnoDB. MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running on Django 1.2.1 with MySQL_python-1.2.3c and can verify that it is indeed creating proper foreign key entries on MySQL.

I suggest that you check if you are using MySQL_python-1.2.3c or better

Comment: I'm using MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg